# rsync exclude directory and all subdirectories

Tags: rsync, centos-7

I'm trying to use `rsync` to synchronise some of my data but I'm unable to exclude what I want. This is my directory tree:

```
tst/
├── st1
│   ├── st11
│   │   └── txt.text
│   ├── st12
│   ├── st13
│   ├── st14
│   └── st15
├── st2
├── st3
├── st4
└── st5
```

I want to exclude directory `st1` and all its subdirectories and files.

I tried using [this Linuxize tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/) with no luck, and these are the commands that I tried:

```
rsync -auvzhe --exclude 'tst/st1/' --exclude 'tst/st1/*/' --exclude 'tst/st1' tst  /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/

rsync -auvzhe --exclude 'tst/st1/' --exclude 'tst/st1/*/' tst  /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/
```

How can I get the copy excluding `st1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, but a subtle mistake caught you out. The `-e` flag requires an argument representing the command to connect to the remote host. In your case there is no remote host so the argument is never used or even validated. Unfortunately for you, the next argument was `--exclude`, which meant that `rsync` saw your `'tst/st1/'` as a directory tree to copy, not one to exclude.

Scenario (to set up your directory tree and example files)

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p tst/st1/st11 tst/st{2,3,4,5}
touch tst/st1/st11/txt.text

ls -R tst
```

Copy everything except the `st1` directory and its contents

```
rsync --dry-run -auv --exclude '/tst/st1/' tst /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/
```

Sample run

```
sending incremental file list
created directory dst
tst/
tst/st2/
tst/st3/
tst/st4/
tst/st5/

sent 178 bytes  received 62 bytes  480.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Remove `--dry-run` when you can see it's doing what you want

Comment: thank you vary mach

Comment: also when I'm running it Im getting this erre rsync error `some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23)` why is that?

Comment: You need to `see previous errors`, like it says